# What do RL and OG mean on a bike chain?

Tags: chain

While changing my bike chain, I noticed letters stamped on some of the links. The old chain (Shimano CN-HG53) has »OG« stamped on some links, while the new one (Shimano CN-HG93) has »RL«. Google doesn't find anything useful. Anyone knows what it means?

[image: Chains]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The RL and OG might be [date codes](http://www.vintage-trek.com/component_dates.htm). Assuming these are 2 different chains, RL would denote 1993-December and and OG would denote 1990-July. If you think they are newer than that, the chart isn't up to date, but if you follow the pattern, RL could be 2019-December and OG could be 2016-July. The second set of dates makes a lot more sense based on what I can see visually from picture.

Comment: Plausible. I have two HG701 chains on current generation Ultegra groups. One is marked RD, and the other RE. Both were purchased in 2019 or 2020.

Comment: Bought the bike used in 2017, with a new chain (the »old one«) put on by the shop. Got the »new one« from amazon a few weeks ago, so it all checks out perfectly.

Comment: Does age of chain matter at all if both are new/unused?  This might be more for stock control, to clear older packaging etc.